# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' | Beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I've just started learning python webscraping and I wanted to learn how to **scrape** the data from the NFL Website to show all the players and their stats, but I'm given this error with the Beautifulsoup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/passing.htm"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

league_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'per_match_toggle sortable stats_table')

for name in league_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = name.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        name = row.find('td', class_ = 'left').text.strip()
        yards = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[7].text
        touchdowns = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[8].text
        print("Name " + name + " Yards " + yards +  " Touchdowns " + touchdowns)
```

Error:

```
name = row.find('td', class_ = 'left').text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens since `find()` can return `None` which, obviously, doesn't have an attribute of `text`.

This can happen when the element you are searching for doesn't exist or your passing the wrong argument to the search function.

You should wrap the problematic section with a `try-except` clause or with an `if else` in order to deal with such scenarios

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll put it all in later today

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you will notice right after James Winston, there's a row of headers. So that `<tr>` tag is made up of `<th>` tags, not `<td>` tags. So it gets to that row, and you say `.find('td')`, which it does not contain so it returns `None`. Then you want to get the text from that, which you get get `.text` from `None`.

So you'll need to either, like the previous post suggested, utilize a try/except or logic that only takes rows with `<td>` tags.

Personally, I'd just use pandas to grab the table, remove that header rows, and iterate through those rows.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/passing.htm"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df = df[df['Player'].ne('Player')]

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    name = row['Player']
    yards = row['Yds']
    touchdowns = row['TD']
    print("Name " + name + " Yards " + yards +  " Touchdowns " + touchdowns)
```

Comment: I really appreciate it, thank you for the help